# how to call a function passed as argument with its parameters already given in D?

Tags: d

I need to call a function passed as argument to another function and it must be passed its needed arguments firstly. In c++, this problem is solved with a macro:

```
#include <iostream>

#define CALL(x) x; \
                std::cout << "Called!" << std::endl;

void foo(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << a * b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    CALL(foo(9, 8)); // I want to pass 2 int parameters inside 'foo' function call
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

It sould output:

```
> 72
> Called!
```

That is exactly how I need to call the function in D. Any ideas?

Edit:
I need this to be done in D. I want to call "foo" inside CALL like:

```
CALL(foo(9, 8)) // and not like: CALL(foo, 9, 8)
```

But I don't know how this is achieved in D. Perhaps with a mixin?

Comment: Is it a question about D or C++?

Comment: *"In c++, this problem is solved with a macro"*. It is not the better way, template method is better (but with a little different syntax).

Comment: @YSC Sorry if I have not been clear, it is about D. I only put an example about how I did it in c++.

Comment: This is misleading and I wasted time on your question, not cool.

Comment: @YSC Maybe you should have actually READ the question in full before rushing to answer it. In the first version, it said "That is exactly how I need to call the function in D. " and I found it very clear that it was a D question, with C++ being the example to show what was needed. It wouldn't bother me if you didn't leave that snarky comment, but you need to check the beam in your own eye before complaining about the mote in the asker's.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I did, and I find it misleading. We all come from diverse cultures, we all understand english with different ease and skill, and finally written communication doesn't convey _tone_. It's everybody's responsability to ensure, check and double check their wording is understood correctly by most users. I try and do it. OP should clearly do it.

Comment: Finally, I commented not OP, but their act. Everybody sometimes act unperfectly, I tend not to juge someone on one data point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In D, you can use a `lazy` function parameter for this.

```
import std.stdio;

void CALL(lazy void x) {
        writeln("before called");
        x;
        writeln("after called");
}

void foo(int x, int y) {
        writeln(x, " ", y);
}

void main() {
        CALL(foo(3, 5));
}
```

D's `lazy` parameter storage class causes the compiler to wrap whatever you give it in a little anonymous function. The above is as if you wrote:

```
import std.stdio;

void CALL(void delegate() x) { // note delegate here in long-form syntax
        writeln("before called");
        x();
        writeln("after called");
}

void foo(int x, int y) {
        writeln(x, " ", y);
}

void main() {
        // and this delegate too
        CALL( delegate() { return foo(3, 5); } );
}
```

But the compiler rewrites it for you. This is why I said `lazy void` - the `void` there is the return type of the hidden function you pass. If it returned `int`, you could use `lazy int` instead.

Note that since `x` inside the `CALL` function is rewritten to be a hidden function, calling it twice will actually evaluate the arguments twice:

```
void CALL(lazy void x) {
        writeln("before called");
        x;
        writeln("after called");
        x;
        writeln("after called again");
}
```

would do:

```
before called
3 5
after called
3 5
after called again
```

Notice how it printed out the arguments twice. Just like the C macro, actually. But if that's not what you want, simply assign it to a temporary yourself:

```
void CALL(lazy int x) {
    auto tmp = x;
    // you can now use tmp as a plain int
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you!